# Count documents in a database directory

Tags: marklogic

Say I have 50 records in directory `/example` in a MarkLogic database.
Is there any way to find size of directory? In this case it should give me 50.
I need it in search API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:directory-query("/example/", "infinity")))
```

Use [xdmp:estimate](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:estimate) over [fn:count](http://docs.marklogic.com/fn:count) to get a fast response.

Comment: Also, if you prefer the Search API, you can do the same thing with  search:estimate().

Comment: Or the tersest form is probably `xdmp:estimate(xdmp:directory($uri, 'infinity'))`

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm curious how we do the same with Java API?

Answer (score 3):

with the java api you could do a search for a given directory and then get the total nr of hits.

```
    DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(host,port, "admin", "****", Authentication.DIGEST);
    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
    StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
    StructuredQueryDefinition querydef = 
            qb.directory(true, "/content/enhanced-rosetta/");
    SearchHandle resultsHandle = queryMgr.search(querydef,new SearchHandle());
    MatchDocumentSummary[] results = resultsHandle.getMatchResults();
    System.out.println("Total count=" + resultsHandle.getTotalResults());
    client.release();
```

Comment: how efficient is that?